# AngularJS, autoscroll and ng-view changing

Tags: angularjs

I m actually developping an application in which I have "long" page, I mean that I have to use a scrollbar to naviguate on a page.

I m actually using autoscroll="true" on my ng-view div, but I m using animations too.

The problem is that angular make the animation before the autoscroll. So it makes something ugly like animate en positionning the view before going to the top.

So, does it exist a method permitting me to autoscroll to top BEFORE animate my div ?

Thanks for advance